# Opencart Error While Updating product

Tags: indexing, import, export, opencart

I am constantly getting an error whenever I try to update any field of a product in the catalog:

```
Notice: Undefined index: points in /home/xxx/public_html/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 130
Notice: Undefined index: price in /home/xxxx/public_html/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 177
Notice: Undefined index: price_prefix in /home/xxxx/public_html/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 177
Notice: Undefined index: points in /home/xxxx/public_html/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 177
Notice: Undefined index: points_prefix in /home/xxxx/public_html/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 177
Notice: Undefined index: weight in /home/xxxx/public_html/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 177
Notice: Undefined index: weight_prefix in /home/xxxx/public_html/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 177Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xxxx/public_html/admin/controller/startup/error.php:34) in /home/xxxx/public_html/system/library/response.php on line 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Were the points fields deleted from the code or the database?

Open admin/model/catalog/product.php and look for:

```
public function getProductOptions($product_id) {
```

Inside that function, you should see:

```
                'points'                  => $product_option_value['points'],
                'points_prefix'           => $product_option_value['points_prefix'],
                'weight'                  => $product_option_value['weight'],
                'weight_prefix'           => $product_option_value['weight_prefix']
```

Also check
admin/controller/catalog/product/product.php for them as well.

Edit:
Also check the javascript in product.tpl (or cart.tpl; wherever you are having this issue)

If the button had moved outside of its designated class, it's trigger would no longer work.
For example; if you move the search box, it's target of "header" isn't being called anymore, so search would not work -- you'll need to change instances of 'header' (in the js call) to the div search now resides in.

May be a similar issue that you're experiencing?

Comment: I have checked in the above files and everything is present in the file as you said . Now what might be the chances of getting that error ?

Comment: @Charan, I revised my answer - might not be a query issue at all; possibly javascript if the field was moved from it's trigger location.